# How to solve this "AssertionError: Must have at least 1 validation dataset for early stopping." in xgboost model=1.6.2

Tags: xgboost, xgbclassifier, skopt, bayessearchcv

from skopt import BayesSearchCV  bayes_cv_tuner = BayesSearchCV(     estimator = XGBClassifier(         n_jobs = 8,         objective = 'binary:logistic',         eval_metric = 'auc',         silent=1,         tree_method='approx', early_stopping_rounds = 10     ),     search_spaces = {         'learning_rate': (0.001, 0.005),         'min_child_weight': (150, 500),         'max_depth': (2, 4),         'max_delta_step': (1, 10),         'subsample': (0.5, .9),         'colsample_bytree': (0.6, 0.8),         'colsample_bylevel': (0.6, 0.9),         'reg_lambda':(100,500),         'reg_alpha': (0.005,.05),         'gamma':  (2.5,10),         'n_estimators': (25, 100),         'scale_pos_weight': (1, 1000)     },         scoring = 'roc_auc',     cv = StratifiedKFold(         n_splits=5,         shuffle=True,         random_state=42     ),     n_jobs = 8,     n_iter = 80,        refit = True,     random_state = 42 )  def status_print(optim_result):     """Status callback during bayesian hyperparameter search"""          # Get all the models tested so far in DataFrame format     all_models = pd.DataFrame(bayes_cv_tuner.cv_results_)              # Get current parameters and the best parameters         best_params = pd.Series(bayes_cv_tuner.best_params_)     print('Model #{}\nBest ROC-AUC: {}\nBest params: {}\n'.format(         len(all_models),         np.round(bayes_cv_tuner.best_score_, 4),         bayes_cv_tuner.best_params_     ))          # Save all model results     clf_name = bayes_cv_tuner.estimator._*class*_._*name*_     all_models.to_csv(clf_name+"_cv_results.csv")

result = bayes_cv_tuner.fit(data_train.iloc[:,1:-1],data_train.iloc[:,-1], callback=status_print)

Comment: Please format your code correctly, include the full error message and explain what you have already tried

Answer (score 0):

You need add eval_set in fit function:

```
evalset = [(feature_validation, target_validation)]
result = bayes_cv_tuner.fit(data_train.iloc[:,1:-1],data_train.iloc[:,-1], eval_set=evalset, callback=status_prin)
```